# Ставить ли запятую перед «как»?

Tags: запятые, обороты-с-как

В предложении «Обязательная процедура для владельцев авто отменена как фиктивная» ставить ли запятую перед «как»? Склоняюсь к тому, что она не нужна.

Answer (score 3):

Правильно, можно подставить *в качестве,* поэтому запятая не нужна. Сравнительного оборота нет у нас.